# quantum mechanics violate Bell's inequality

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, quantum-mechanics

I have this function
$$
\begin{aligned}
F\big(\theta_a,\theta_b,\phi_a,\phi_b\big) = \ &
– \big[\cos \theta_a  \cos \theta_b \big] 
– \big[\sin\theta_a \sin\theta_b \sin\phi_a \sin\phi_b\big] 
\\ 
& – \big[\cos\phi_a \cos\phi_b \sin\theta_a \sin\theta_b\big].
\end{aligned}
$$
I want to find the max values and the unknown variables $(\theta_a,\theta_b, \phi_a,\phi_b)$ analytically (by hand) and in MATLAB, the range for $\theta_a, \theta_b$ is $(0:\pi)$ and for $\phi_a, \phi_b$ is $(0:2 \pi)$. 
Actually, the max value should be $2 \sqrt{2}$ that QM predicted to violate Bell's inequality. 
As I tried in matlab I got $1$.

Any help will be valuable.Thanks

Comment: Please format your question correctly: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: What are these angles: $\theta_a,\theta_b,\phi_a,\phi_b$?

Comment: Of couse. the maximum is $1$.  This function is bounded from above by $$-\min\Big\{\cos\left(\theta_a-\theta_b\right) , \cos\left(\theta_a+\theta_b\right)\Big\}\,.$$

Comment: You gave two different ranges for $\theta_a,\theta_b$ and none for $\phi_a,\phi_b$.

Comment: the rang for theta_a,b is between 0 and pi while for phi_a,b is between 0 and 2*pi.

Answer (score 0):

This is $-\left(\cos\theta_a\cos\theta_b+\sin\theta_a\sin\theta_b\cos(\phi_a-\phi_b)\right)$. Thus, the extreme values are taken for $\cos(\phi_a-\phi_b)=\pm1$, and they are $-\cos(\theta_a\pm\theta_b)$, so the minimum is $-1$ and the maximum is $1$.

Comment: the range for theta(a,b) is from 0 to pi while for phi(a,b) is from 0 to 2*pi.

Comment: @Raja: Does that somehow affect the validity of this answer?

Comment: yes because i am testing two qubit in quantum mechanics that violate Bell's inequality which equal to 2sqrt2

Comment: @Raja: Perhaps that was a misunderstanding. I was asking whether the ranges you specified for the angles affect the validity of my answer. Do you think my answer isn't valid for those ranges? I believe it is.

Comment: Yes  i think as i told you the max is 2sqrt2 but i don't how to find it from this function also the nuknown variable theta (a,b), phi (a,b)

Comment: @Raja: You're just repeating stuff you wrote in the question. matlab told you it's $1$. Batominovski told you it's $1$. I'm telling you it's $1$. If you still insist it's $2\sqrt2$, then I'm not sure why you came here to ask a question.

Comment: If you think the ranges make a difference, please provide an argument for that.

Comment: Okay , can you try it by hand to find the max value and the unknown variables.

Comment: @Raja: Of course I can, but I won't. I proved that it's $1$. If you disagree, you should provide an argument. I'm not going to be responding here anymore unless you provide arguments for your claims.